# How to add string/URI matching in XACML

Tags: authorization, policy, xacml, abac, authzforce

I am trying to learn XACML. 
I was trying to implement PDP and was trying to fiddle with policy

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" PolicyId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:conformance-test:IIA1:policy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" Version="1.0">
    <Description>
        Policy for Test IIA001.
    </Description>
    <Target/>
    <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:conformance-test:IIA1:rule">
        <Description>
            Can Teacher Read record from Faculty Service
        </Description>
        <Target>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">TEACHER</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"/>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:anyURI-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI">http://localhost:8765/faculty/</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI" MustBePresent="false"/>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"/>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"/>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
        </Target>
    </Rule>
</Policy>
```

I want to change to something like regular expression which will accept http://localhost:8765/faculty/*  or contains `http://localhost:8765/faculty`

````
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI">http://localhost:8765/faculty/</AttributeValue>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [anyURI-regexp-match](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/errata01/os/xacml-3.0-core-spec-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc489959655) or the [anyURI-contains](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/errata01/os/xacml-3.0-core-spec-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc489959651), or - even better - the [anyURI-starts-with](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/errata01/os/xacml-3.0-core-spec-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc489959651) functions  (see the links for the exact function identifiers).

In general, all standard functions are specified in [appendix A.3 of the XACML 3.0 standard](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/errata01/os/xacml-3.0-core-spec-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc489959642), then each XACML implementation may add functions of their own and/or enable you to plug in your own, in which case it depends on which implementation you use.

Comment: I would add that there is no need to implement your own PDP as you stated ("I was trying to implement PDP") - just use AuthZForce which is open source Java and up-to-date or if you want commercial, look up Axiomatics.

Comment: @SyedAliUmairTirmizi please accept the answer if OK for you.